# Passing ArrayAccess from Controller to View in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I try to learn Laravel 4 and I have found it - so far - pretty great. But Blade templaes seem dfficult to me, less intuitive than Smarty for instance.

I have a small problem. I try to push my data from Controller to a View. I do this:

```
public function getGame($id, $slug = null) {
    $game['info'] = Game::find($id);
    $game['genres'] = Game::find($id)->genres()->get();
    $game['dev'] = Game::find($id)->developers()->get();

    $this->layout = View::make('user')->with('game',$game);
}
```

Pretty straightforward, isn't it? For now, my View is just `{{ $game['info']->title }}`. But it seems that it doesn't see my variable (throwing "Undefined variable: game"). What can I do? Can I post the data in that array format (I assumed from the docs that I can).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the last line of your code. You either return a view like

```
return View::make('user')->with('game', $game);
```

or do something like this:

Create protected $layout = 'my_layout.blade.php' in your controller and create the file my_layout.blade.php and put it into views folder. In it write something like

```
@yield('content')
```

Then, create your user.blade.php and create a section like this

```
@section('content')
    ....
@stop
```

Finaly, at the end of your getGame function

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('user')->with('game', $game);
```

Home this make sense to you.

Btw, why not define 'genres' and 'developers' relationships in your Game model and then use eager loading like

```
$game = Game::with('genres', 'developers')->find( $id );
```

and pass this to the view. Then access title like $game->title, genres like $game->genres->... etc.

Regards,
Vlad